# Facebook pop framework: view go crazy after rotation

Tags: ios, facebook, rotation, core-animation, facebook-pop

I'm playing with new [Facebook pop framework](https://github.com/facebook/pop) and it's awesome!

But when i start trying to do rotations i had some problems and have no guess why!

I have UIPanGestureRecognizer connected to main controller's view and in the center i have another view which will be rotating.

Here is the panReceiver `IBAction`:

```
- (IBAction)panReceived:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender {

    CGPoint translation = [sender translationInView:sender.view];
    CGPoint velocity    = [sender velocityInView:sender.view];

    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

        POPDecayAnimation *rotationAnim = [POPDecayAnimation animationWithPropertyNamed:kPOPLayerRotationY];

        rotationAnim.velocity = @(velocity.x);

        [self.circle.layer pop_addAnimation:rotationAnim forKey:@"rotationAnim"];

    } else {

        self.circle.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(translation.x, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

    }

}
```

So i simply change rotation angle over Y axis while user do dragging and when it's done make decay animation based on velocity. But something go wrong, here is how:

> [image: rotation issue]

I will appreciate any help!

Comment: hi @Oleg_Korchickiy, do you solve this problem now?

Comment: It is a bug. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/35264452/1378447