# How to flip a UIView horizontally using Facebook PoP ios framework?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, facebook

I am using facebook Pop framework for iOS.
How do i make a view flip horizontal (on its Y axis) ?

Here is my code:

```
func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    aBoolValue = !aBoolValue
    sender.userInteractionEnabled = false
    let layer = sender.layer

    // First let's remove any existing animations
    layer.pop_removeAllAnimations()
    layer.removeAllAnimations()
    let rotation: POPSpringAnimation = POPSpringAnimation(propertyNamed:kPOPLayerRotationY)

    if aBoolValue == true {
        rotation.toValue = M_PI
        sender.setTitle("G", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    } else {
        rotation.toValue = 0
        sender.setTitle("P", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }

    rotation.completionBlock = {(anim: POPAnimation! , finished: Bool) -> Void in
        layer.pop_removeAllAnimations()
        sender.userInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    layer.pop_addAnimation(rotation, forKey: "rotation")
```

The results of this is that it flips as expected, but after about 5-6 flips, the animation begins to flip randomly and not normally. How do i flip a view horizontally the right way?

Comment: Why the downvotes with no reason why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug in pop library. see https://github.com/facebook/pop/issues/71

People can create somewhat similar animation with `UIView.animateWithDuration:` method.

for example

```
private func get3DTransformation(angle: Double) -> CATransform3D {

    var transform = CATransform3DIdentity
    transform.m34 = -1.0 / 500.0
    transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, CGFloat(angle * M_PI / 180.0), 0, 1, 0.0)

    return transform
}

private func flipAnimation(view: UIView, completion: (() -> Void) = {}) {

    let angle = 180.0
    view.layer.transform = get3DTransformation(angle)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .TransitionNone, animations: { () -> Void in
        view.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
        }) { (finished) -> Void in
            completion()
    }
}
```

---

```
func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {

    aBoolValue = !aBoolValue
    if aBoolValue == true {
        sender.setTitle("G", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    } else {
        sender.setTitle("P", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }

    flipAnimation(sender)
}
```